# Concat multiple CSV rows into 1 in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, concatenation

I am trying to contact the CSV rows. I tried to convert the CSV rows to list by pandas but it gets 'nan'  values appended as some files are empty.
Also, I tried using zip but it concats column values.

```
    with open(i) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        res = ""
        for i, j in zip(lines[0].strip().split(','), lines[1].strip().split(',')):
            res += "{} {},".format(i, j)
            print(res.rstrip(','))
        for line in lines[2:]:
            print(line)
```

I have data as below,

Input data:-
[Input CSV Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOLgg.png)

Expected Output:-
[Output CSV Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBKTi.png)

The number of rows are more than 3,only sample is given here.
Suggest a way which will achieve the above task without creating a new file. Please point to any specific function or sample code.

Comment: if there are more then 3 rows --- after how many rows will to be concattenated will a new row created?

Comment: why not create a new file - you just want to print the data to view it?

Comment: Do you have control over the Input Data? If you do, I'd just spend time fixing that file because that's just a horribly formatted csv.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Regarding not creating a new file, I was exploring the inline mechanism to make updates, though the final list in your solution, when added to CSV in write mode, did the job.

Comment: @ALollz The file was the output of web scrapping done in bits and pieces. Indeed horribly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes your first line contains the correct amount of columns. It will read the whole file, ignore empty data ( ",,,,,," ) and accumulate enough data points to fill one row, then switch to the next row:

Write test file:

```
with open ("f.txt","w")as f:
    f.write("""Circle,Year,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
abc,2018,,,,,,,,,,,,
2.2,8.0,6.5,9,88,,,,,,,,,,
55,66,77,88,,,,,,,,,,
5,3.2,7

def,2017,,,,,,,,,,,,
2.2,8.0,6.5,9,88,,,,,,,,,,
55,66,77,88,,,,,,,,,,
5,3.2,7

""")
```

Process test file:

```
data = [] # all data
temp = [] # data storage until enough found , then put into data 

with open("f.txt","r") as r:
    # get header and its lenght
    title = r.readline().rstrip().split(",")
    lenTitel = len(title)
    data.append(title)

    # process all remaining lines of the file
    for l in r:
        t = l.rstrip().split(",") # read one lines data
        temp.extend( (x for x in t if x) ) # this eliminates all empty ,, pieces even in between 
        # if enough data accumulated, put as sublist into data, keep rest
        if len (temp) > lenTitel:
            data.append( temp[:lenTitel] )
            temp = temp [lenTitel:]
    if temp:
        data.append(temp)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['Circle', 'Year', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'], 
 ['abc', '2018', '2.2', '8.0', '6.5', '9', '88', '55', '66', '77', '88', '5', '3.2', '7'], 
 ['def', '2017', '2.2', '8.0', '6.5', '9', '88', '55', '66', '77', '88', '5', '3.2', '7']]
```

Remarks:

- your file cant have leading newlines, else the size of the title is incorrect.
- newlines in between do not harm
- you cannot have "empty" cells - they get eliminated

Comment: This just works perfectly. For new rows, I meant that equivalent number of columns will also be added.

Comment: @Swapnil it works, until you have missing values - then it breaks and you have to fix your data. glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

As long as nothing weird is going on in the files, something like this should work:

```
with open(i) as f:
  result = []
  for line in f:
    result += line.strip().split(',')
  print(result)
```

Comment: This works but the data has 'nan' entries which need to be separately taken care of.